# SVM model does not support probabiliy estimates?

Tags: svm, libsvm

I am doing some classification task with Support Vector Machines (SVM). 
I am using libSVM (with Matlab support) to predict probability estimates matrix. However, the libSVM displays message that;
Model does not support probabiliy estimates
Below is my sample code;
(train_label contains labels for training data and test_label contains label for test data)

```
    model = svmtrain(train_label, train_data, '-t 2 -g .01 -c 0.7 -b 1);
    [y,accuracy,prob_estimates]=svmpredict(test_label,test_data,model,'-b 1');
```

Can someone tell me if there is something wrong with the way I am doing it? Any help/suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: You are missing a ' at the end of the options string in your training command.

Answer (score -2):

Probability can only be used with regression (epsilon-SVR, nu-SVR) svm type
Try using regression svm type and it will give probability output

Comment: -1 C-SVC can give approximated probability outputs via Platt scaling.